# How to change the name of a View already mapped to an Action Method in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, mapping, actionmethod

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application developed with C# and Razor.

I have a View, **View1**, mapped to and Action Method, **ActionMethod1**. In order to respect naming conventions I would like to rename **View1** to **View2** and still keep it mapped to the same action method.

The problem is that when I change the name to **View2** the View is not anymore recognized by **ActionMethod1**.

I know that I can specify the name of the View *explicitly* as first parameter in the overload method `View(viewName, model)` but since there is already a mapping between **ActionMethod1** and **View1** I found this solution quite "dirty".

How can I make the Action Method **ActionMethod1** understand that it should refer to **View2** and give up on looking for **View1**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the [ActionNameAttribute](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2008/11/20/asp-net-mvc-actionnameattribute-and-actionmethodselector-class/).  That will allow you to change the name of the action although I am thinking that you most likely will have to use the method where you explicitly return

```
View(viewName, model)
```

in order to get the results you want.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. However my problem is much simpler, I do not need to do it at runtime but just in Visual Studio 2010. The information about the mapping Actionmethod - View must be stored somewhere